# Filtering pandas dataframe to restrict within a given range of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like this

```
2684    A878    2015-01-01  False   M13
2685    A878    2015-01-01  False   M50
2686    A879    2015-01-01  False   M96
5735    A879    2015-01-02  False   M19
... ... ... ... ...
89487   A879    2015-01-30  False   M38
89488   A879    2015-01-30  False   M35
89489   A879    2015-01-30  False   M33
89490   A879    2015-01-30  True    M66
89491   A879    2015-01-30  False   M4
```

I would like to filter the data frame by a particular value for the second column( == A879) and by a particular offset from a date. For example if my second column value is A879 and my desired date is 2015-01-15 then I want all the rows that has A879 for the second column and more that 2 but less than 5 days before the 2015-01-15. So it should look like.

```
89489   A879    2015-01-12  False   M33
89490   A879    2015-01-13  True    M66
89491   A879    2015-01-14  False   M4
```

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
import datetime as dt

REFERENCE_DATE = dt.date(2015, 1, 15)

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df[
    df["date"].dt.date.between(
        REFERENCE_DATE - dt.timedelta(days=5), REFERENCE_DATE - dt.timedelta(days=2)
    )
    & df["code"].eq("A879")
]
```

?

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Also I want to concurrently apply the second condition(== A879)

Comment: @robotlover please check my update. I don't know what the names of your column with 'A879' is, but you should replace "code" with that

Comment: Thank you. That works. But do you know how I could change the code so that I include informations like -2 to -5 days ? So instead of explicitly specifying the dates. Something like 2015,1,15 (-2) to (-5) days.

Comment: use `dt.timedelta(days=-2)`, for example

Comment: if we were to use iterrow to go through each row then 
`for index, row in df.iterrows:` and using `row["date"]` gives a datetime format which I am unable to add with date?